# Multiple Inner Sub-queries not returning as expected

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Below are my SQL tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[My_Employee_Schedule] (
[Emp_Sch_Id]    INT      IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Schedule_Date] DATETIME NULL,
[Start_Time]    DATETIME NULL,
[End_Time]      DATETIME NULL,
[Emp_ID]        INT      NULL,
[Job_ID]        INT      NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Emp_Sch_Id] ASC),
FOREIGN KEY ([Emp_ID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[My_Employee] ([Employee_Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY ([Job_ID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[My_Job_Type] ([Job_Type_Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[My_Job_Type] (
[Job_Type_Id] INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Job_Title]   NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Job_Type_Id] ASC)
);
```

I am creating an ASP.NET C# web app, and am trying to do the following with this data:

- Display *Schedule_Date* in an outer ASP repeater
- Then display *Job_Title (FROM THE My_Job_Type table)* using the FK in the *Employee_Schedule* table.

Rather than display jobs connected with the below days, all jobs are being displayed.

Here is my current SQL (which is displaying "Waiter", "Driver" & "Busser"):

```
SELECT Job_Title 
FROM My_Job_Type 
WHERE Job_Type_Id IN (
    SELECT Job_Id 
    FROM My_Employee_Schedule 
    WHERE Schedule_Date IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT CAST(Schedule_Date AS DATE) As Schedule_Date 
        FROM My_Employee_Schedule 
        WHERE Start_Time BETWEEN @startReportDate AND @endReportDate))
```

Below is the current output I have:
[image: snip1]

Here is the current data:

> **Emp_Sch_Id      Schedule_Date      Start_Time      End_Time Emp_ID Job_ID**
>
> 1 03/06/2017 00:00:00 03/06/2017 09:00:00 03/06/2017 10:00:00 5 2
>
> 2 03/06/2017 00:00:00 03/06/2017 11:30:00 03/06/2017 12:30:00 6 1
>
> 3 03/06/2017 00:00:00 03/06/2017 14:00:00 03/06/2017 15:00:00 5 3
>
> 4 03/06/2017 00:00:00 03/06/2017 12:00:00 03/06/2017 13:00:00 4 2
>
> 5 03/06/2017 00:00:00 03/06/2017 12:15:00 03/06/2017 15:15:00 4 2
>
> **Job_Type_Id Job_Title**
>
> 1 Waiter
>
> 2 Driver
>
> 3 Busser

Comment: In My_Job_Type table, "Waiter", "Driver" & "Busser" are the only rows. I think this current SQL statement is displaying all of the rows within each div. But, the Job_Id [Foreign Key] attaches a specific Job with each row in the Employee_Schedule table. Rather than display within each div, I want to only display jobs whose FK is associated with a Employee_Schedule row.

Comment: For example, only _Waiter_ should appear under Saturday because the _Employee_Schedule_ row who's Schedule_Date is 3/6/2017 has a **Job_ID** equal to 1

Comment: can you post the data in those tables? It's pretty hard for us to know if the results are correct without it.

Comment: @scsimon Hi, I've posted the table data above.

Comment: depending on what you have your variables set to, the query i posted should return the correct results but you only have 3/6 in this dataset and are showing dates outside of this range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can gather, it seems like you only need an `inner join` versus the nested uncorrelated sub-queries.

```
select distinct
    t.Job_Title
from
    My_Job_Type t
    inner join
        My_Employee_Schedule s on 
        s.Job_ID = t.Job_Type_ID
where
    s.Schedule_Date between @startReportDate and @endReportDate
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for that solution. If I wanted to display the Employee_Name underneath the Job_Title now, do I need another join? Btw, Employee_Name is a column in the Employee table, Emp_ID above is the FK.

Comment: Probably since i don't see the employee name in any of those tables you provide. I'm guessing it'd join on the My_Employee_Schedule table using the Emp_ID column....

Comment: If I post my additional table above, would you be able to update your answer to include the solution for that also? As it still falls under the category of multiple sub-queries?

Comment: @user2911539 Stack Overflow recommends a new question be opened, with a reference link to this question otherwise the thread would never end and this would turn into a blog versus a Q&A forum.

Comment: No problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44313197/how-to-use-joins-and-nested-repeaters-with-sql-server Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem @user2911539, i see the question has traversed more into the C# realm and outside of the DB so glad they could help.