# Using Joins and Nested Repeaters with SQL Server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to create an Employee Scheduler, and am having some trouble displaying the data.

I want to first display *Schedule_Date*s, and then underneath those, the *Job_Type*s that will be occurring on that day.

Then, I am trying to display the *Employee_Name*, *Start_Time* & *End_Time* of that Schedule.

So far, I have the Dates & Job Types displaying, but I am having trouble trying to display the employee names & start/end shift times.

Below is my current output:[image: snip1]

Here is my current C#:

```
 private void bindRepeaterPerPerson()
{
    conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    conn.Open();
    comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT Start_Date, End_Date FROM My_Subscription WHERE Subscription_Id = 1", conn);
    SqlDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        startDate = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["Start_Date"]);
        endDate = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["End_Date"]);
    }
    conn.Close();
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    { 
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT CAST(Schedule_Date AS DATE) As Schedule_Date FROM My_Employee_Schedule WHERE Start_Time BETWEEN @startReportDate AND @endReportDate", con))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startReportDate", startDate);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@endReportDate", endDate);
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                sda.Fill(dt);
                repSubscription1.DataSource = dt;
                repSubscription1.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
}

protected void repSubscription1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    conn.Open();

    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        Repeater repJobs = (Repeater)(e.Item.FindControl("repJobs"));
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT j.Job_Title FROM [dbo].[My_Employee_Schedule] as s INNER JOIN My_Job_Type j on s.Job_ID = j.Job_Type_Id WHERE Schedule_Date = @Date", conn);
        DateTime myDate = Convert.ToDateTime(DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "Schedule_Date"));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", myDate);
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        repJobs.DataSource = dt;
        repJobs.DataBind();
    }
    conn.Close(); 
}
```

HTML:

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="repSubscription1" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="repSubscription1_ItemDataBound">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <div class="col-lg-2">
                            <div class="panel panel-default">
                                <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color: #3A6EA5; color: white">
                                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                                        <%# Eval("Schedule_Date", "{0:dddd, dd MMMM yyyy}") %>
                                    </h4>
                                </div>
                                <!--panel-heading-->
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    <asp:Repeater ID="repJobs" runat="server">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <%# Eval("Job_Title") %>
                                            <br /><br />
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:Repeater>

                                </div>
                                <!--panel-body-->
                            </div>
                            <!--panel-default-->
                        </div>
                        <!--col-lg-2-->
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
```

Below are my SQL tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[My_Employee_Schedule] (
[Emp_Sch_Id]    INT      IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Schedule_Date] DATETIME NULL,
[Start_Time]    DATETIME NULL,
[End_Time]      DATETIME NULL,
[Emp_ID]        INT      NULL,
[Job_ID]        INT      NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Emp_Sch_Id] ASC),
FOREIGN KEY ([Emp_ID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[My_Employee] ([Employee_Id]) ON 
DELETE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY ([Job_ID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[My_Job_Type] ([Job_Type_Id]) ON 
DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[My_Job_Type] (
[Job_Type_Id] INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Job_Title]   NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Job_Type_Id] ASC)
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[My_Employee] (
[Employee_Id]   INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Employee_Name] NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[Company_Id]    INT           NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Employee_Id] ASC),
FOREIGN KEY ([Company_Id]) REFERENCES [dbo].[My_Company] ([Company_Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

And also, my table data:

```
Emp_Sch_Id  | Schedule_Date       | Start_Time          | End_Time            | Emp_ID | Job_ID
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1           | 03/06/2017 00:00:00 | 03/06/2017 09:00:00 | 03/06/2017 10:00:00 | 5      |  2
2           | 03/06/2017 00:00:00 | 03/06/2017 11:30:00 | 03/06/2017 12:30:00 | 6      |  1
3           | 03/06/2017 00:00:00 | 03/06/2017 14:00:00 | 03/06/2017 15:00:00 | 5      |  3
4           | 03/06/2017 00:00:00 | 03/06/2017 12:00:00 | 03/06/2017 13:00:00 | 4      |  2
5           | 03/06/2017 00:00:00 | 03/06/2017 12:15:00 | 03/06/2017 15:15:00 | 4      |  2

Employee_Id | Employee_Name
----------------------------
4           | Damien
5           | John
6           | Owen
```

Comment: You can make this whole thing easier by not using DataTables. Use strongly typed model objects, and bind those to your repeater.

Comment: @mason Hi, can you provide a link to these strongly typed model objects? I haven't worked with them before. Do these work with multiple SQL tables?

Comment: I bet you have. I'm just talking about a class that describes your objects. That's it. Just a plain old class. Then you bind that as your DataSource instead of using a DataTable.

Comment: @mason So do I retrieve data from the database & create an instance of the class with that?

Comment: Yep, exactly. And that shouldn't be done in your page code behind. Have a data layer elsewhere that handles it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, install dapper (or another ORM), and create your model:

```
public class MyData 
{
    public DateTime Schedule_Date {get;set;}
    public DateTime Start_Time {get;set;}
    public DateTime End_Time {get;set;}
    public string Employee_Name {get;set;}
    public string Job_Title {get;set;}
}
```

Create your DAL class:

```
public class DAL
{
    public static string connectionString = ...;

    public IEnumerable<MyData> GetMyClassByRange(DateTime start, DateTime end)
    {
        var sql = @"SELECT Schedule_Date, Start_Time, End_Time, Employee_Name, Job_Title
                    FROM My_Employee_Schedule ed
                    JOIN My_Employee e ON ed.Emp_ID = e.Employee_Id
                    JOIN My_Job_Type jt ON ed.Job_ID = jt.Job_Type_Id
                    WHERE Start_Time BETWEEN @startReportDate AND @endReportDate";

        conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        conn.Open();

        var data = conn.Query<MyData>(sql, new { startReportDate=startDate, endReportDate=endDate});
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Ok, now that you have your DAL, you can massage it into the form that you want, which is by date, then by Job, with employees and their start dates. So let's go ahead and do that in your page code behind:

```
public IEnumerable<MyViewModel> GetData()
{
    //var test = new List<MyData>();
    //test.Add(new MyData { Schedule_Date = new DateTime(2017, 6, 3), Start_Time = new DateTime(2017, 6, 3, 9, 0, 0), End_Time = new DateTime(2017, 6, 3, 10, 0, 0), Job_Title = "Waiter", Employee_Name = "John" });
    //test.Add(new MyData { Schedule_Date = new DateTime(2017, 6, 3), Start_Time = new DateTime(2017, 6, 3, 11, 0, 0), End_Time = new DateTime(2017, 6, 3, 12, 0, 0), Job_Title = "Driver", Employee_Name = "Own" });
    //test.Add(new MyData { Schedule_Date = new DateTime(2017, 6, 3), Start_Time = new DateTime(2017, 6, 3, 14, 0, 0), End_Time = new DateTime(2017, 6, 3, 15, 0, 0), Job_Title = "Busser", Employee_Name = "John" });
    //test.Add(new MyData { Schedule_Date = new DateTime(2017, 6, 3), Start_Time = new DateTime(2017, 6, 3, 12, 0, 0), End_Time = new DateTime(2017, 6, 3, 13, 0, 0), Job_Title = "Waiter", Employee_Name = "Damien" });
    //test.Add(new MyData { Schedule_Date = new DateTime(2017, 6, 3), Start_Time = new DateTime(2017, 6, 3, 12, 15, 0), End_Time = new DateTime(2017, 6, 3, 15, 15, 0), Job_Title = "Waiter", Employee_Name = "Damien" });
    var MyDal = new DAL();
    var test = MyDal.GetMyClassRange(DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddYears(1));
    var result = test
        .GroupBy(x => new {x.Schedule_Date, x.Job_Title})
        .GroupBy(x => x.Key.Schedule_Date)
        .Select(x => new MyViewModel {Start_Date = x.Key, Jobs = x.Select(y => new MyJobsView {Job_Title = y.Key.Job_Title, Datas = y})})
        .ToList();

    return result;
}
```

And now let's make your repeaters and bind it all up:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptDate" runat="server" ItemType="WebApplication1.MyViewModel" SelectMethod="GetData">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <br/>
        Start Date: <%# Item.Start_Date %>
        <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptJob" ItemType="WebApplication1.MyJobsView" DataSource="<%# Item.Jobs %>">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <br/>Job Title: <%# Item.Job_Title %>
                <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptJob" ItemType="WebApplication1.MyData" DataSource="<%# Item.Datas %>">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        Name: <%# Item.Employee_Name %>
                        Start: <%# Item.Start_Time %>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, if this works then it really does clear things up !! Can I put this _MyData_ class at the bottom of Default.aspx or do I need to create a new place for this? Also, where does the second piece of code go?

Comment: @user2911539 Where you put it is really up to you. But if it's going to be reusable, then don't put it in your page's code behind.

Comment: @mason Thanks. And where do I place the other code mentioned above? The `var sql = @"...`?

Comment: To be honest, this would be even easier with Entity Framework as an ORM, but I used dapper as an example because it's more low level (and easier to explain)

Comment: @RobertMcKee OK, would you be able to go through how to populate the class from the tables in chat? I haven't done it this way before, and I'm not sure how to proceed

Comment: @mason Hi, would you be able to open a chat & help me get through how to populate the new class with SQL table data? I haven't done it this way before, I've just used Datatables as always

Comment: It's all there already.  That is what `var data = conn.Query<MyData>(sql,...)` line does.  data at that point will contain a list of MyData filled from your database.

Comment: And to be honest, my webforms foo is a bit out of date.  I rarely do webforms anymore, but from what I recall, what I have above should be pretty close.

Comment: @RobertMcKee OK, so I've created a new class called MyData. Where do I place the `var sql =@...` code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145661/discussion-between-robert-mckee-and-user2911539).